# print exact all characters from lines from one file to one file in batch file

Tags: batch-file

Here i am printing line no 1 to 5 from a file to another file.its working fine but one small issue that the lines are trimming from left side,i do not want to trim,it should be same as the input file.

`infile.txt`:

```
<RCO-XXX-AGENT>
 <CREATED>2018-06-28 10:19:09</CREATED>
 <FORMAT>
  <VARIABLE>
   <EOR>/010</EOR>
   <EOC>/009</EOC>
   <CTR>5</CTR>
```

`code`:

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :Print_Lines > outfile.txt
endlocal
:Print_Lines
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cur=0
for /f "delims==" %%i in (infile.txt) do (  
set /a cur=cur+1 
if !cur! geq 1 (
if !cur! leq 5 (
  for /f "tokens=*" %%j in ( "%%i") do (
  echo %%j
  )
 )
)
)
endlocal
exit /b 0
goto :eof
```

`outfile.txt`:

```
<RCO-XXX-AGENT>
<CREATED>2018-06-28 10:19:09</CREATED>
<FORMAT>
<VARIABLE>
<EOR>/010</EOR>
```

Comment: What happens when you change `"tokens=*"` to `"delims="`?

Comment: You must place `goto :EOF` before `:Print_Lines` to avoid this section to be executed twice...

Comment: If you want your own [head](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=7481#p49690) batch file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second loop is useless

It should work :

```
echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
call :Print_Lines > outfile.txt
endlocal
:Print_Lines
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set cur=0
for /f "delims==" %%i in (infile.txt) do (  
set /a cur=cur+1 
if !cur! geq 1 (
if !cur! leq 5 (
  echo %%i
 )
)
)
endlocal
exit /b 0
goto :eof
```

In your exemple, the spaces at left are not printed because they are considered as delimiter character

Comment: The `if !cur! geq 1 (` is also useless as is the `goto :eof` following an exit; the exit implies an endlocal. Shorter: `Set /a cur+=1`

Comment: Should have an `IF` command to check if the counter is greater than 5 and then use a `GOTO` to break out of the `FOR` command.  Otherwise if the file is hundreds of lines long the code is wasting time processing all the extra lines.

Comment: Did you intend for this to run `:PrintLines` twice?

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest this method:

```bat
@Echo Off
Set "Num=5"
<"infile.txt" (For /L %%A In (1,1,%Num%) Do (Set "_="
        Set /P "_="
        SetLocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        Echo=!_!
        EndLocal))>"outfile.txt"
```

*Where you can adjust the value to `Num` as necessary.*